# TimeStamp in Cache-time attacks on AES

Tags: timing-attack

I have recently read about AES cache timing attacks. More specifically, I read Daniel Bernstein paper [Cache-timing attacks on AES](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf). I have a question about the code in Appendix A:

```
unsigned int timestamp(void)
{
unsigned int bottom;
unsigned int top;
asm volatile(".byte15;.byte 49" : "=a"(bottom),"=d"(top));
return bottom;
}
```

What does timestamp methode do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the meaning of Intel x86 assembly instructions; this site is for questions about cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

The opcode 15 49 (0F 31 - Intel opcodes are more typically listed in hexidecimal) is the RDTSC instruction; this loads the number of cycles since the last rest into EDX:EAX.

By running this function, running some code, and then running this function again, and subtracting the results, you get precisely how long the code takes (in number of CPU cycles).